# Attach and Remove a CSS class using ngClass in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I am building an app using Angular JS. I am using `ng-repeat` to loop over list of items. My code is something like below,

```
<div class="names" ng-repeat="room in rooms" ng-click="getMessages(room.id); active = true; " ng-class="{'blue_act': active}">

    <div class="con_cir col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <div class="grey_cir">
            <div class="wht_cir">
                <div class="circle1">
                    <div class="cir_txt">{{room.title | nameInitials}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="em_info col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">

        <div class="em_pr">
            <div class="name boldfnt col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7" ng-class="{'normal-font': active}">
                {{room.title}}
            </div>
            <div class="date col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                {{room.lastActivity | date: 'd/M/yyyy'}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="subject boldfnt col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            Here is your copy of your coupans.
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to apply the class `blue_act` only when the particular row is selected. I don't want to write any function in the controller to achieve this.

For example When I click the `Demo#16` only that row will have the *blue background*. And when I click the `e2Spark` only that row will be highlighted using the *blue color*. Is it possible with only `ng-click` and `ng-class`?

**Screenshot**
[image: Screens]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new property on controller's scope, called 'selectedRow', and assign room name to it on click.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kKaHLDM0bsK77Zi4u3BL?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.rooms = [
    {name: 'room1'},
    {name: 'room2'},
    {name: 'room3'},
  ];

  this.selectedRow = this.rooms[0].name;
});
```

```css
.blue_act {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  selected row: {{main.selectedRow}}
  <div class="names" ng-repeat="room in main.rooms" ng-click="main.selectedRow = room.name" ng-class="{'blue_act': main.selectedRow == room.name}">

    <div class="con_cir col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
      <div class="grey_cir">
        <div class="wht_cir">
          <div class="circle1">
            <div class="cir_txt">{{room.name }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes. This is working. Thanks. But why you use `MainCtrl as main`. I just want to know the reason

Comment: updated the code to not use $scope, and use 'controller as' syntax. see this link on benefits of this approach: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `click` event with this `ng-click="getMessages(room.id); reset(); room.active = true; "`
and do same for `ng-class` where you are using as like `ng-class="{'normal-font': room.active}"`

Add below `reset function` in your code if you want select at a time single row.

```
$scope.reset= function(){
   angular.forEach($scope.rooms, function(room) {
   room.active=false;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your ng-click

```
ng-click="getMessages(room.id); room.active = !room.active;"
```

in your ng-class

```
ng-class="{'normal-font': room.active }"
```

Answer (score 0):

With no controller function you could use

```
<div class="names" ng-repeat="room in rooms" ng-click="getMessages(room.id);room.active=!room.active;" ng-class="{'blue_act': room.active}">
...
</div>
```

Or if you just wanted to have one active at the same time this should work:

```
<div class="names" ng-repeat="room in rooms" ng-click="getMessages(room.id);selectedRoom=room.id;" ng-class="{'blue_act': selectedRoom===room.id}">
...
</div>
```